# Problem of opennebula installation on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: installation, ubuntu-18.04, opennebula

I am trying to install opennebula on ubuntu 18.04 but i recieved this error:

## apt-get install opennebula opennebula-sunstone opennebula-gate opennebula-flow

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
opennebula-flow is already the newest version (5.5.90-1).
opennebula-gate is already the newest version (5.5.90-1).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
opennebula : Depends: libcurl4 but it is not installable
opennebula-sunstone : Depends: python-numpy but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Any suggestion please to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you totally sure that you have ubuntu 18.04?

I've got similar error trying to install opennebula packages for ubuntu 18.04 on ubuntu 16.04 system by mistake.

Try to check your current OS release:

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, later I found that I missed a step

Copy and Run the below code:

**wget -q -O- https://downloads.opennebula.org/repo/repo.key | sudo apt-key add -**

after running that, try installing:

apt-get install opennebula opennebula-sunstone opennebula-gate opennebula-flow